# Add a user to my Azure subscription

Tags: azure

I'm just starting on this, been going through the Microsoft documentation and the lightbulb hasn't come on yet...

How do I add a user to my subscription so they can login?  From there I just need to limit them to Azure Media Services.

I've seen instructions on web for clicking a "Users" button from subscription, but I do not see that.  I've tried adding a user through the Azure Active Directory as well with no luck...

Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks!

James

Comment: The button is now *Access control (IAM)* :D

Answer (score 6):

OK, so I figured this out:

1)  Add your user to Active Directory (I added guest user)

2)  Go to subscriptions and to your IAM panel

3)  Ensure that your new user has access to at least Read the subscription. 
 (When I did this it allowed me to view my Azure resources as other user)

4)  From there I created a role in a JSON file and used New-AzureRmRoleDefinition -InputFile to import it.  IMPORTANT:  Make sure for permissions you have Microsoft.Media/* and Microsoft.Media/mediaservices/*

5)  Once I did this I went to my Media Services IAM panel and added the user to my new Azure Media Services role.

6)  Presto!  It started working.

Thanks to all who responded to this thread!!!

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried adding a user through the Azure Active Directory as well
>   with no luck...

This is exactly what you need. Create a user in Azure Active Directory (at portal.azure.com) and grant them access to your subscription with the custom role to allow only Azure Media Services (I don't think there's a built-in role for that). To do that, follow the links (to create custom role, to create user and to assign user that role). I don't think you can create custom role using portal, so you will need REST API or powershell\CLI\SDK

Links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/add-users-azure-active-directory

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  I posted a more complete answer below in hopes that it helps others!!!