# I cannot sign-in Azure service from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core

My Visual Studio information

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview
Version 16.7.0 Preview 4.0
VisualStudio.16.Preview/16.7.0-pre.4.0+30310.162
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03056

Installed Version: Community

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.7.523.48425
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   16.1.0.2035807+72d099b977d3a85e65fa3b0614ca8cfc803fef02
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   16.7.523.48425
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   16.7.523.48425
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Node   1.0
This package contains the Data Lake integration nodes for Server Explorer.

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.4.6000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   16.7.523.48425
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.4.6000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

BusinessObjectEditor   1.0
Information about my package

C# Tools   3.7.0-4.20359.1+b90347a69117be7181e2f03a991790634981eddb
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

CodeRush for Roslyn   20.1.5.0
DevExpress CodeRush for Roslyn package.

CodeRush for Roslyn Tool Windows   20.1.5.0
DevExpress CodeRush for Roslyn Tool Windows package.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

ConvertToDevExtremeCommand Extension   1.0
ConvertToDevExtremeCommand Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

CreateLayoutWizard   1.0
Create layout wizard.

DevExpress Reporting Extension   1.0
A Visual Studio extension that invokes the Report Designer editor for report definition REPX files.

DevExpress Reporting Tools Extension   1.0
Extends Visual Studio with tools required for the Report Designer editor.

DevExpress.DeploymentTool   1.0
A useful tool for deploying DevExpress assemblies.

DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.DynamicPackage   1.0
DevExpress VSIX Package

DevExpress.ExpressApp.DesignPackage   1.0
DevExpress VSIX Package

DevExpress.Win.LayoutAssistant Extension   1.0
DevExpress.Win.LayoutAssistant Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

IntelliCode Extension   1.0
IntelliCode Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Microsoft Azure HDInsight Azure Node   2.4.6000.0
HDInsight Node under Azure Node

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.4.6000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.4.6000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Node   1.0
Azure Stream Analytics Node under Azure Node

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 - v2.9.30701.1

Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
Simplifying the configuration of Azure DevOps pipelines from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   2.1.79+ge3567815aa.RR
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

NuGet Package Manager   5.7.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62006.04220
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   16.0.20702.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   3.7.0-4.20359.1+b90347a69117be7181e2f03a991790634981eddb
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools 10.10.0.0 for F# 4.7   16.7.0-beta.20329.1+19c9e2f1b21a66ec90fefae79988b33fc16744fc
Microsoft Visual F# Tools 10.10.0.0 for F# 4.7

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions (Preview)   1.0
View, manage, and diagnose containers within Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers
```

I cannot sign-in Azure service from Visual Studio 2019

[image]

I also tried log-in by Firefox with username and password to https://portal.azure.com and successs. But I cannot use the same account to login to Azure service from Visual Studio 2019 Community - preview.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Go to "Default Apps" in Windows and change the "Web Browser" to Internet Explorer and try again. Sometimes VS and other MS applications doesnt work with other browsers.

Comment: did  the error solved now?

Answer (score 3):

Close down all Visual Studio Instances.

Navigate to `%LocalAppData%` and remove a folder called `“.IdentityService”` (this is a hidden file)

Delete all temporary files - `%temp%`

Delete cookies from your browser.

Comment: Removing the %LocalAppData%\.IdentityService fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Removing %LocalAppData%\.IdentityService worked for me as well. I were already logged in using my AD credientials trough Visual Studio top right corner login. However, I didn't see Sign In -button in Tools | Options | Azure Service Authentication | Account Selection. The button was completely hidden.

After removing .IdentityService folder and VS 2022 restart the button appeared and I logged into my Azure account.

Comment: For me it worked after I signed in to Visual Studio using different account and then switched back to initial one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a new user in Azure and adding it to my subscription, then assigning it the Contributor role. Here is a walk through of creating a new user: [Add a user to my Azure subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103763/add-a-user-to-my-azure-subscription)

After that you should be able to use Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio to authenticate using the newly-created account, then view the subscription resources (functions, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after I signed in to Visual Studio using different account and then switched back to initial one.